# paper-menu don't display on foreground

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements

I have this problem:

[image: weird]

When I visit page the paper-menu displays correctly but when i scroll down and back to top, the paper-menu is behind the div (with id nav). I tried to play with z-index and positons but nothing worked.

CSS:

```
paper-scroll-header-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:  #eee;
}

paper-toolbar {
  /* custom toolbar height */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6a1b9a;
  overflow: visible;
}
#nav {
  background-color: #6a1b9a;
}
```

HTML:

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel condenses keep-condensed-header header-height="100" condensed-header-height="50">

  <paper-toolbar>

   <h1>Some text</h1>
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-menu-button>

   <div id="nav" class="flex bottom fit">
            <paper-tabs noink  >
              <paper-tab >Tab1</paper-tab>         
              <paper-tab >Tab2</paper-tab>
              <paper-tab >Tab3</paper-tab>
              <paper-tab >Tab4</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
  </div>

  </paper-toolbar>

  <div class="content">

    <sample-content size="100"></sample-content>

  </div>

</paper-scroll-header-panel>
```

[If you want to play around with code...](http://roadiction.com/bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/demo/demo8.html) (I don't know how to import polymer to jsbin or codepin. It says something about no third party using.)

Comment: The hiding is caused by the translate property added inline by JS. You want to show the header throughout the page?

Comment: @ManojKumar no, with header is everything in order. I just want to display paper-menu correctly above header. It works well when you reload the page, but when you scroll down and to the top the paper menu is behind div with id nav.

Comment: having the same issue